# Dockerize exists Django Postgres project:on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting web_1 | TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have a django project using postgresql run in local host without any problem.

And then I started to dockerize it:

original settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypass',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ' ',
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

Then I run:

```
docker-compose build
```

Image build successfully.

Then I run :

```
docker-compose up
```

Error:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I know it is because container not able to connect with my local Postgresql db.What should I do,any friend can help?

Comment: How are you running your local postgres, as part of your compose?

Comment: Thank you for your reply my local postgres is running all the time,what else need I do?

Comment: Who closed my question, that question is about mysql not postgres and it did not solve my issue?Please open my question immediately!

Comment: You need to click on "Reopen" at the bottom of your question to request it be re-opened. What exactly about the other question doesn't answer yours? `'HOST': 'host.docker.internal',` should work if you're on windows or mac?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ,where should I run 'HOST': 'host.docker.internal' in terminal or in postgresql client ?

Comment: Your DATABASES setting, try changing HOST to `'host.docker.internal'`

Comment: @IainShelvington thank you so much!It works!Can you post your answer ,I want to check it!

Comment: Sorry, can't add an answer to a closed question. Glad it helped though

Comment: @IainShelvington have you nice weekend :)!